# How to show $\ \int_1^\infty\frac1xdx\ $ diverges (not using the harmonic series)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was reading up on the harmonic series,
$H=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$, on Wikipedia, and it's divergent, as can be shown by a comparison test using the fact that

$\begin{aligned}H&=1+\frac12+\left(\frac13+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18\right)+\cdots\\&\geq 1+\frac12+\left(\frac14+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18\right)+\cdots\\&=1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\cdots,\end{aligned}$

where the expression on the right clearly diverges.

But after this proof idea was given, the proof idea using the integral test was given. I understand why $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\geq \int_1^n \frac{dx}x$, but how is it shown that $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}x$ is divergent without using the harmonic series in the following way:
$H_n-1\leq \int_1^n \frac{dx}x\leq H_n$, and then using this in the following way, by comparison test:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}H_n=\infty\implies\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(H_n-1)=\infty\implies\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n \frac{dx}x=\infty$.

So to summarize, is there a way to prove that  $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}x$ without using the fact that $H$ diverges?

Comment: A primitive of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\log x$, so $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{x} = \log b - \log a$ for $0 < a < b$.

Comment: Yes, but then there is the question of how to prove that $\log x\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Is it possible to do without using the harmonic series, like somehow using the fact that the logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function?

Comment: Maybe you can use the Bertrand criterion for the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{\alpha} \log(t)^{\beta}} dt$  with $\alpha =1$ and $\beta =0$ so you get the divergence of the integral.

Comment: Given $N$, we know $\log x>N$ for all $x>e^N$. So yes, $\log x$ diverges. Your logic concerning the harmonic series is backwards, BTW. We do not use the harmonic series' divergence to prove $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}dx$ or $\log x$ diverges - we use the latter to prove the former!

Comment: Yes, using that it's the inverse of $\exp$ and noting that $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \exp(x) = +\infty$ shows that $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \log x = +\infty$ [for $x > e^K$, we have $\log x > K$].

Comment: @anon Is there something fundamentally wrong with using the harmonic series to show that $\log x$ diverges? Just wondering, seeing your comment.

Comment: No - you can use the harmonic series' divergence to prove the integral's divergence. But the fact you're asking how to prove it a different way implicitly suggests this is how it is done in practice ... and that's not my experience.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Let $x = y/2.$ Then

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x} = \int_2^\infty\frac{dy}{y}.$$

That is a contradiction unless both integrals equal $\infty.$

Comment: Nice indeed. +1

Comment: +1 very nice! Of course it works because $\int_1^2 \frac 1x dx  \neq 0$  which is obvious but worth mentioning I think :)

Comment: This is a nice proof. But proving the substitution rule for improper integrals would probably take more work than another simple way of proving the integral diverges. Regardless, the proof is pretty interesting

Answer (score 10):

Since
$$
\int_a^{2a}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x=\log(2)
$$
we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^{2^n}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x
&=\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x+\int_2^4\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x+\cdots+\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^n}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\\[6pt]
&=n\log(2)
\end{align}
$$
Let $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this one.  Change variables $x=t^{1/2}, dx = (1/2)t^{-1/2}\,dt$.

Then
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\;dx =
 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^{1/2}}\;\frac{t^{-1/2}}{2}\;dt 
= \frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}\;dt
$$
Now $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x} > \int_1^2 \frac{dx}{2} = \frac{1}{2} > 0$.  So conclude it is $+\infty$.

Or, if we are allowed properties of $e^x$:

Substitute $x=e^t, dx=e^t\,dt$ so
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\;dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^t}\;e^t\;dt
=\int_0^\infty dt = \infty.
$$

Comment: The first approach shows either that the integral is $0$ or that the integral diverges. It might be worth mentioning, if obvious, that the integral is not $0$.

Answer (score 4):

This was pointed out in the comments above, so since no one else wrote this in an answer, I will.

You have (by definition)
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\; dx 
&= \lim_{t\to \infty}\int_1^t \frac{1}{x}\; dx \\
&=  \lim_{t\to \infty} \ln(x)\large]_1^t \\
&= \lim_{t\to \infty} \ln(t) - \ln(1) \\
&= \lim_{t\to \infty} \ln(t) \\
&= \infty.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This seems to be the simplest way to do it! I'm surprised no one posted it before you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^{2^n}\frac{1}{u}\,du&=\int_1^2\frac{1}{u}\,du+\int_2^4\frac{1}{u}\,du+\int_4^8\frac{1}{u}\,du+\cdots +\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^n}\frac{1}{u}\,du\\\\
&\ge \left(\frac{1}{1}\right)\left(2-1\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(4-2\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(8-4\right)+\cdots +\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\left(2^n-2^{n-1}\right)\\\\
&=1+1+1+\cdots +1\\\\
&=n
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\int_1^{2^n}\frac{1}{u}\,du\ge n \to \infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty$$

And we are done!

Comment: Nice proof! Though you have got the inequalities wrong, each term is less than or equal to the function evaluated at the *right* end point (since it is a decreasing function) times the length of the interval, so you get the bound n/2. Doesn't change the idea just a mistake

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{ac}^{bc}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{cx=ac}^{cx=bc}\frac{d(cx)}{cx}=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\therefore\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{dx}{x}=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x}=+\infty$$